# SAS name error when using a variable from a looping macro inside a hash dataset statement

Tags: hash, dataset, sas, nested-loops

Any advice on how I can modify this problem code line below to get my datasets named without error?

I have a dataset where I want to match treatment firms (4400) with about 100,000 control firms by 48 industries and 14 years, then nearest size without replacement.  My method below may be a bit clunky, but I am learning as I go.  I am splitting the treatment and control datasets into 48x14 groups, (after this I will try to run nearest match without replacement code through some type of loop).

I have already used a variant of the below hash code to make 48 datasets out1...out48.  Now I am attempting to further subset each of these 48 datasets into the 14 years through using the below code.  I am receiving an error dataset creation line, where I am trying to create 48x14 datasets named out12004, out22004, out32004. . .out482013

Problem code line (about 2/3 down the code below):    hh.output (dataset: 'out'||&i||put(year, best.-L)) ;

The SAS errors look like this:

ERROR: The value OUT           12004 is not a valid SAS name.

ERROR: An error has occurred during instance method OM_OUTPUT(505) of "DATASTEP.HASH".

Here is the full code (modified from 
[Is it possible to loop over SAS datasets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17984153/is-it-possible-to-loop-over-sas-datasets) and[SUGI30 paper 236-30](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/236-30.pdf)

```
 %MACRO process_datasets(mdataset);
      data &mdataset.;
      set &mdataset.;
        data _null_ ;
        dcl hash hoh (ordered: 'a') ;
        dcl hiter hih ('hoh' ) ;
        hoh.definekey ('year' ) ;
        hoh.definedata ('year', 'hh' ) ;
        hoh.definedone () ;
        dcl hash hh () ;
        do _n_ = 1 by 1 until ( eof ) ;
        set out&i. end = eof ;
        if hoh.find () ne 0 then do ;
        hh = _new_ hash (ordered: 'a') ;
        hh.definekey ('industry','cik', 'year', '_n_') ;
        hh.definedata ('industry','cik','year','eventdat', 'at', 'roa') ;
        hh.definedone () ;
        hoh.replace () ;
        end ;
        hh.replace() ;
        end ;
        do rc = hih.next () by 0 while ( rc = 0 ) ;
        hh.output (dataset: '_'||&i||put(year, best.-L)) ;
        rc = hih.next() ;
        end ;
        stop ;
     run;

     data _null_;
       file 'tmp.csv' mod dsd dlm=',';  *saving everything to the same file;
       set &mdataset.;
       put (_all_) (+0);
     run;

%MEND process_datasets;

%MACRO loop_through_all;
    %DO i = 1 %to 48;
       %process_datasets(out&i.);
     %END;
%MEND loop_through_all;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a few notes about the technical points in the other answer - ie, "Where the problem is not directly coming from, although both are examples of poor coding."

&i is indeed accessible here, although I would suggest it is poor style to use it the way you do.  Macro variables that are relied upon in interior macros should be defined as macro parameters; that makes it clear where they came from.  However, technically, this isn't wrong, see this:

```
%macro caller;
%do i=1 %to 5;
  %called;
%end;
%mend;
%macro called;
%put &i;
%mend called;

%caller;
```

However, it would be better to make i a paramter, such as `%macro called(i=);`, to make your macro more clear, and more reusable.

Second, lack of quotes is in fact not the direct problem, although again it does point to an issue and is a solution in a way.  SAS does convert the numerics in that to a character value - otherwise you'd get a very different error message; however, it does so in a way that is not helpful.  The most similar implementation of what you did is to add `compress` around it.  That is because the problem is how SAS converts numerics to text; `&i` is a number (`1` in your example).  It needs to be converted to `"1"`, and instead it is converted using `best12.` to `"           1"`.  That is a problem.

```
hh.output (dataset: compress('_'||&i||put(year, best.-L))) ;
```

That works.  A better implementation would be to intentionally convert to a character value.  Macro parameters are very easy to convert: just add `" "` around them.

```
hh.output(dataset: cats('_',"&i.",year);
```

`cats` strips all spaces off, and makes the `-L` unnecessary.  It would work just as well with `&i`, although it's certainly better to add quotes.

I would add that you might consider why you're subsetting these.  I don't think there's anything conceptually wrong with doing so, but odds are if you are doing something by year, you can use `by year` and get away with not subsetting them - keeping them in one dataset per treatment group (and perhaps even `by group year`?).  Further, you might be able to do this in fewer steps.  What are you going to do, finally?  Let's say you had one dataset for each group/year.  What code would you then run?  It may be that you can write that in one or a few steps without breaking out 48x14 datasets, which is probably not efficient.  If you're interested in finding out, start a new question with the details of what you'd like to do with just a pair of datasets.

Comment: I used cats('_',"&i.",year); and this solved it--Thank you very much.  I agree my approach may be a bit cumbersome but given the macro I used next, I still think that I needed separate datasets.

Answer (score 0):

To address your specific point regarding the output line:-

```
hh.output (dataset: '_'||&i||put(year, best.-L)) ;
```

A few notes:-

- The argument for dataset must be quoted, e.g. `..(dataset: "Out123")`.  Currently, yours is not.
- The major macro does not have access to the macro variable `&i`.  This is created in the calling macro and is available in that scope only.  You could add another parameter to the major macro and send `&i` that way.

In truth, though, the code your creating looks very difficult to maintain; a hash in a macro is a nightmare to debug.  And if you're producing code that creates lots of output datasets that should set alarm bells ringing; the `by` statement in SAS allows the applying of criteria to separate groups within a dataset and is definitely preferable to many datasets.

Let's look at the problem: you're matching controls to treatment using variables that will yield multiple control groups per treatment?  You would then choose a control per treatment based on some distance criteria?

For the first part, a `Proc SQL` merge sounds about right.  You'll get a long dataset with each treatment firm repeated the number of times it was matched to a control.  Then sort by `treatment descending [distance criteria]` and pick the first one per `by` group.  And that should be that.  Of course, I'm sure I've misunderstood something...

A final point; you could just look for matching algorithms in SAS, particularly 'optimal matching' or 'greedy matching'.  In my experience, SAS is not great for matching, especially if it involves a random element (yours doesn't), but you should be able to find code more useful than what you're working with right now.

Comment: Both of your main points are incorrect.  The problem with the output is not related to the lack of quotes, at least not directly.  Further, &i. is clearly defined; hence the 1 before 2014.  I don't know about the text after that - probably reasonable advice - but the technical points are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be able to simplify your above code greatly by using wildcards on your `set` statement instead of using multiple set statements to "loop over them".

For example, the below code would step through all of your datasets that begin with one of the prefixes so that you can work on them without multiple `set` statements.

```
data all;
  set out1:
      out2:
      out3:
      out4:
      ;
run;
```

That may even allow you to remove the need for a macro which in turn would simplify the code.  That existing code looks very difficult to maintain/debug so I think simplifying it is the first step.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what he's doing.  (Admittedly, I only have a vague idea myself.)  He's not setting multiple datasets together, he's making multiple datasets out of other (fewer) datasets.

Comment: In that case I sure did misunderstand... I just saw the set statement with a dynamic dataset name being incremented by a DO loop and made that assumption.

Comment: I actually don't understand the point of that being in a data (something).  I don't understand why it's not a `data _null_`.  But who knows...

Comment: Could be for debugging?  I was specifically referring to the set statement on line 12 of the code though.